# Singular value decomposition - How can I know which value applies to which vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ and it's SVD decomposition $A = USV$.
I read that the diagonal entries of $S$ are equal to the singular values of $A$ and that the columns of $U$ and $V$ are the singular vectors. Since I have no backgroud in SVD I'm forced to ask: does that mean that $S(1,1)$ corresponds to the first column in $U$ and  $S(2,2)$ corresponds to the second column in $U$ and so on? (until there are no more columns left in $U$ and then we switch to $V$)

Answer (score 1):

The factorization is usually written as $A = U S V^T$, with $U$ and $V$ orthogonal and $S$ diagonal.  Equivalently, $A V = U S$.

Note that the first column of $AV$ is $A v_1$, and that the first column of $U S$ is $s_1 u_1$.  (Here $v_1$ is the first column of $V$, $u_1$ is the first column of $U$, and $s_1$ is the first diagonal entry of $S$.)

Because the first columns of $AV$ and $US$ are equal, we see that
\begin{equation*}
A v_1 = s_1 u_1.
\end{equation*}

Similar equations hold for the remaining columns.